# comment-reply.js is not loading

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I'm building my own website within WordPress from scratch. It's not really a new theme, just everything from the beginning, starting with an index file, header, footer, single, comments, functions etc. Utilizing WordPress' features where ever I need them.

I've always been doing good at that, except from when I discovered the Nested comment feature and wanted to tap into that.

But.

I can't get the freaking **comment-reply.js** to load. Doesn't matter whether I run it in functions or in the header. Even if I just use the raw

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' )
```

that should load on each page.

It completely ignores it. If I call the .js file directly by naming the hardcoded url it loads, but this is not the way it's supposed to be coded. It's just a bad work-around.

```
<?php if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments') ) { ?>
 <script src="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

I've even tried to empty all code out so that the ONLY thing the website does is to load the script but without results. And yes nested comments are activated in settings. I've also tried reinstalling on different domains in case the WP code got screwed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify if the issue is that the script is not *loading* (i.e. the script URL is broken/404's), or that it's not *running* (i.e. throwing an error, check the browser console)

Comment: It's not loading at all. WP completely ignores it.

Writing it like this in the header.php works, but that's not how it's intended.

 <?php if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments') ) { ?>

  <script src="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js"></script>

 <?php } ?>

Comment: Check your conditions. Are the comments open on that page and are your nested comments enabled. If you have disabled any of these the comments won't show up.

Comment: There is no 404. Just ignores the call unless I hardcode the actualy path in an old fashion way. But then that will be broken if WP makes changes to it at a later stage.

Comment: Yes, all open and all enabled. And the page also has comments visible. Including nested ones.

Comment: Do you have any plugins active?

Comment: I've tried to disable all plugins also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this helps you out?
Please make a backup from `functions.php` and add following `function`.

```
/**
 * Add .js script if "Enable threaded comments" is activated in Admin
 * Codex: {@link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/}
 */
function wpse218049_enqueue_comments_reply() {

    if( is_singular() && comments_open() && ( get_option( 'thread_comments' ) == 1) ) {
        // Load comment-reply.js (into footer)
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply', '/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.min.js', array(), false, true );
    }
}
add_action(  'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse218049_enqueue_comments_reply' );
```

> Note: see codex on how to [enqueue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

Comment: No sorry, that's what is not working for me. The wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); is completely being ignored by WP. But I've done it the manual way and that works out just fine. I was just wondering if anyone knew why it is like that.

Comment: @Larsps, I would check the issue with the `twentysixteen theme` and all `plugins` disabled. Imho is the 'works out just fine'  already pointing you on possible new issues into the future. As already mentioned by yourself, you have no clue what the cause is which makes Wordpress behaving like it does right now for you, so stable warranties are already gone I would say. But you are right, as long it seems to work for you be happy :) (*updated the `plugin` though, for others it probably will work like a charm*)

Comment: I've checked already with standard themes and there it loads just fine. So when my own theme is completely stripped for everything, there much be something that trickers/enables comment-reply that I currently don't have. I don't know whether I'll ever figure it out since I seem to be the only person on the Internet that has this problem (I've done my research). But my bad work around is working just fine for now http://lowhangingfruits.com/work/visual-proof-of-why-having-smartphone-optimised-websites-for-smartphones-matters/

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too. I found out that the `comment-reply.js` is loaded at the bottom of the page, so you won't find it in your header. Make sure you have `wp_footer()` inside your `footer.php`.